# If ${(X_t)}$ is strictly stationary then $X_{t_1}+\ldots+X_{t_n} \overset{d}{=} X_{t_1+k}+\ldots+X_{t_n+k}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, time-series

Let ${(X_t)}_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be strictly stationary. I want to show that for all  $t_1, \ldots, t_n \in \mathbb{Z}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ it holds
$$
X_{t_1}+\ldots+X_{t_n} \overset{d}{=} X_{t_1+k}+\ldots+X_{t_n+k}
$$

---

My reasoning:

Strict stationary means that the finite dimensional distributions are shift-invariant, i.e. for all $t_1, \ldots, t_n \in \mathbb{Z}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ it holds

$$
(X_{t_1}, \ldots,X_{t_n}) \overset{d}{=} (X_{t_1+k}, \ldots X_{t_n+k}).
$$

If the distribution of the vector $(X_{t_1}, \ldots,X_{t_n})$ is shift-invariant, then, it seems to me, so should be the distribution of $X_{t_1}+\ldots+X_{t_n}$.

---

But how can one show it rigorously?

Comment: What you need is that if $Z=Z'$ in distribution then $g(Z)=g(Z')$ in distribution for every continuous function $g$. Use this for $$
Z=(X_{t_1}, \ldots,X_{t_n})\qquad Z'=(X_{t_1+k}, \ldots X_{t_n+k})
$$ and $$g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_1+\cdots+x_n$$

Comment: @Did, is it necessary that $g$ be continuous? I think any function would do.

Comment: @Arash Good point, I had in mind the conditions for convergence in distribution, which are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned by Did in the comments, you need to show that if $X\stackrel{d}{=}Y$, then for every function $g$, $g(X)\stackrel{d}{=}g(Y)$. I am tempted to give an information theoretic proof of this using data processing inequality for any kind of $f-$divergence, which includes KL-divergence. Data processing inequality writes as:
$$
D(P_X||P_Y)\geq D(P_{g(X)}||P_{g(Y)}).
$$
Note that KL-divergence is positive. Moreover $X\stackrel{d}{=}Y$ if and only if $D(P_X||P_Y)=0$. Hence:
$$
D(P_{g(X)}||P_{g(Y)})=0\implies  g(X)\stackrel{d}{=}g(Y).
$$

Comment: Hmmm... What about the remark that $[g(X)\in B]=[X\in g^{-1}(B)]$ and $[g(Y)\in B]=[Y\in g^{-1}(B)]$? Seems more direct.

Comment: @Did, yes of course, I think I would do it your way normally. I call this a kind of curiosity somehow.